# RSA_DH vs ECDH implementation

Tags: rsa, elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman

In ECDH protocol is possible, naturally, to use the same algorithm for calculate a secret key for both communication parties (Alice and Bob for example). It is possible to design also a same algorithm for the parties comunication in the RSA-DH protocol?

Comment: ECDH is a (basic) protocol to agree on a shared key. RSA (in your context I think) is a key transport mechanism. What do you mean by "RSA-DH" (a reference maybe?)?

Comment: Do you imply that you are using DH for encryption and RSA for signature generation and verefication in same scheme?